# How do I auto load a database jar in Groovy without using the -cp switch?

Tags: java, scripting, groovy, classpath

I want to simplify my execution of a Groovy script that makes calls to an Oracle database. How do I add the ojdbc jar to the default classpath so that I can run:

```
groovy RunScript.groovy
```

instead of:

```
groovy -cp ojdbc5.jar RunScript.groovy
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Summarized from *Groovy Recipes*, by Scott Davis, **Automatically Including JARs in the ./groovy/lib Directory**:

1. Create `.groovy/lib` in your login directory
2. Uncomment the following line in ${GROOVY_HOME}/conf/groovy-starter.conf

   `load !{user.home}/.groovy/lib/*.jar`
3. Copy the jars you want included to `.groovy/lib`

It appears that for Groovy 1.5 or later you get this by default (no need to edit the conf), just drop the jars in the /lib dir.

Comment: Not sure if this would be preferred though.  There are times when I would rather use the "default classloader" of java.  In that case I can put jars into jre/lib/ext to get autoloaded to the default classloader.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few ways to do it. You can add the jar to your system's CLASSPATH variable. You can create a directory called .groovy/lib in your home directory and put the jar in there. It will be automatically added to your classpath at runtime. Or, you can do it in code:

```
this.class.classLoader.rootLoader.addURL(new URL("file:///path to file"))
```

Comment: Loading the JAR dynamically doesn't work for me unless I also instantiate any classes within the JAR dynamically as well.  For example, if MyClass is in the JAR, I have to construct it like this:

def myObj = Class.forName("com.whatever.MyClass").newInstance()

Thus, it's way better just to include the JAR file somewhere within the groovy-starter.conf directories, unless there's a way around this that I don't know about.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be using @Grab in the code:

```
    @GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)
    @Grab('com.oracle:ojdbc6:12.1.0.2.0')
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver").newInstance()
```

Answer (score 1):

`groovy` is just a wrapper script for the Groovy JAR that sets up the Java classpath. You could modify that script to add the path to your own JAR, as well, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the following [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to the first line of your Groovy script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy -cp ojdbc5.jar
```

Then, mark the script executable:

```
chmod u+x RunScript.groovy
```

Now, running the script by itself will set the classpath automatically.

```
./RunScript.groovy
```

Comment: he's saying that he wants to simplify the script NOT moving the command parameter within groovy