# How do I include jars in a groovy script?

Tags: java, groovy, jar, classpath

I have a groovy script that needs a library in a jar. How do I add that to the classpath? I want the script to be executable so I'm using `#!/usr/bin/env groovy` at the top of my script.

Comment: Looks like this was already asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254385/how-do-i-auto-load-a-database-jar-in-groovy-without-using-the-cp-switch

Comment: As stated in answers below, it is best to use `#!/bin/sh` and then call `groovy` with whatever arguments you want.  The minimum would be `#!/bin/sh\n groovy -cp PATH-OR-JAR $@` to pass all of the arguments passed on the command line to the groovy command.  In Windows it would be `groovy -cp PATH %*`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you really have to you can also load a JAR at runtime with:

```
this.getClass().classLoader.rootLoader.addURL(new File("file.jar").toURL())
```

Comment: Heh, definitely missed the "Adding things to the classpath" section first time I read that.

Comment: I could not get that classloader to work... anyone else able to use it?

Comment: There are limitations not covered in the documentation when running with a shebang(#!). I explained them further [down](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8945888/54396). @Zombies, the classloader technique only works when you don't need to import classes from that .jar. Imports are resolved at prior to the script running and importing the .jar

Comment: @Zombies you can get it to work by delaying the instantiation using reflection, see the example here: https://gist.github.com/tknerr/42258e761f2a0f95a92b#comment-1315206

Comment: unfortunately, the link does not work anymore

Comment: Link is now dead, maybe try: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:file_dependencies

Comment: It doesn`t wor for me.

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method addURL() on null object

Comment: It's still working, you just then need to create dynamically an instance `def h = Class.forName("com.Hello").newInstance();
`, then you should be able to use it.

Answer (score 58):

Starting a groovy script with `#!/usr/bin/env groovy` has a very important limitation - **No additional arguments can be added.** No classpath can be configured, no running groovy with defines or in debug. This is not a [groovy](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GMOD-226) issue, but a limitation in how the shebang (`#!`) works - all additional arguments are treated as single argument so `#!/usr/bin/env groovy -d`  is telling `/usr/bin/env` to run the command `groovy -d` rathen then `groovy` with an argument of `d`.

There is a workaround for the issue, which involves bootstrapping groovy with bash **in the groovy script.**

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                 
//usr/bin/env groovy  -cp extra.jar:spring.jar:etc.jar -d -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/etc/myapp/log4j.xml "$0" $@; exit $?

import org.springframework.class.from.jar
//other groovy code
println 'Hello'
```

All the magic happens in the first two lines. The first line tells us that this is a `bash` script. `bash` starts running and sees the first line. In `bash` `#` is for comments and `//` is collapsed to `/` which is the root directory. So `bash` will run `/usr/bin/env groovy  -cp extra.jar:spring.jar:etc.jar -d -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/etc/myapp/log4j.xml "$0" $@` which starts groovy with all our desired arguments. The `"$0"` is the path to our script, and `$@` are the arguments. Now groovy runs and it ignores the first two lines and sees our groovy script and then exits back to `bash`. `bash` then exits (`exit $?1`) with status code from groovy.

Comment: Can this be done with a Windows batch file?

Comment: Nice tip - although it doesn't appear to work in a Windows Cygwin shell, as the double slash in //usr/bin/env is not collapsed.

Comment: On Linux (BSD needs more logic to do readlink -f), the following picks out the current scripts path and includes that in the classpath.

`// 2>/dev/null; SCRIPT_DIR="$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")"; exec groovy -cp "$SCRIPT_DIR" "$0"`

Answer (score 26):

My Favorite way to do this is with Groovy Grapes. These access the Maven Central Repository, download the referenced jar, and then put it on the classpath. Then you can use the library like any other library. The syntax is really simple:

```
@Grab(group='com.google.collections', module='google-collections', version='1.0')
```

You can read more details [here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html). One major advantage here is that you don't need to distribute your dependencies when you distribute your script. The only drawback to this method is that the Jar has to be in the Maven repository.

Comment: Broken link for here

Answer (score 25):

You can add the jars to $HOME/.groovy/lib

Comment: works for me (using Groovy 2.1.2 with Windows 7)

Comment: This is great except when you are running so many Groovy processes that you exhaust your open files limit.

Answer (score 10):

You can also try out Groovy Grape.   It lets you use annotations to modify the classpath.   Its experimental right now, but pretty cool.   See [docs.groovy-lang.org/.../grape](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html)

Answer (score 6):

The same as you would in Java.

This is an example of running a MySQL status monitoring script. mysql.jar contains the MySQL connector that I call from script status.groovy.

groovy -cp mysql.jar status.groovy ct1

Comment: On Windows it did not work out for me with  `-cp mysql.jar`. I had to use `-cp ./mysql.jar` instead

Answer (score 6):

Below is a combination of [Patrick's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8945888/106189), [Maarteen Boekhold's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30503877/106189), and foozbar's comment that works with both Linux and Cygwin:

```
#!/bin/bash
// 2>/dev/null; SCRIPT_DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "$0" )" && pwd )"
// 2>/dev/null; OPTS="-cp $SCRIPT_DIR/lib/extra.jar:$SCRIPT_DIR/lib/spring.jar"
// 2>/dev/null; OPTS="$OPTS -d"
// 2>/dev/null; OPTS="$OPTS -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/etc/myapp/log4j.xml"
// 2>/dev/null; exec groovy $OPTS "$0" "$@"; exit $?

import org.springframework.class.from.jar
//other groovy code
println 'Hello'
```

How it works:

- `//` is a valid groovy comment, so all of the bash commands are ignored by Groovy.
- `//` will return an error, but the error output is redirected to `/dev/null` and is therefore not displayed.
- bash executes commands following a semicolon even though the previous command failed.
- `exec` replaces the current program in the current process without forking a new process. Thus, groovy runs within the original script process (`ps` shows the process as the script rather than the groovy executable)
- The `exit $?` statement following `exec groovy` prevents bash from trying to interpret the rest of the script as a bash script, and also preserves the return code from the groovy script.

The above bash trick is more convenient in some cases than [the RootLoader trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/306168/106189) because you can use regular import statements within the script.  Using the RootLoader trick forces you to load all of the classes using reflection. This is fine in some situations (such as when you need to load a JDBC driver), but inconvenient in others.

If you know your script will never be executed on Cygwin, then using Patrick's or Maarteen's solution will likely result in slightly better performance because they avoid the overhead of generating and throwing away an error.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to @Patrick his answer, which helped me a lot, I recently discovered another trick.

If you add lots of jars to the classpath all on one line, things can become quite unreadable. But you can do the following!

```
#!/bin/bash
//bin/true && OPTS="-cp blah.jar -Dmyopt=value"
//bin/true && OPTS="$OPTS -Dmoreopts=value2"
//usr/bin/env groovy $OPTS "$0" $@; exit $?

println "inside my groovy script"
```

Let your imagination run wild on how complex a command line you can break down this way into manageable pieces

Maarten

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use it **right away before the `import` declarations** it is possible like this :) :

```
// printEmployees.groovy
this.class.classLoader.rootLoader.addURL(
   new URL("file:///C:/app/Dustin/product/11.1.0/db_1/jdbc/lib/ojdbc6.jar"))
import groovy.sql.Sql
sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl", "hr", "hr",
                      "oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource")
sql.eachRow("SELECT employee_id, last_name, first_name FROM employees")
{
   println "The employee's name is ${it.first_name} ${it.last_name}."
}
```

Taken from this [javaworld.com article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073966/core-java/groovy-scripts-master-their-own-classpath-with-rootloader.html).