# invoking groovy without passing a classpath each time

Tags: groovy, classpath

In a windows environemnt, how can I invoke groovy without having to specifiy the classpath for a given set of JARs each time? I am trying to create a script for an admin so that he can just type `groovy deploy [project name]`.

Edit: Is there anyway to do this through a class path environment variable? Or some other centralized configuration?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306139/how-do-i-include-jars-in-a-groovy-script and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254385/how-do-i-auto-load-a-database-jar-in-groovy-without-using-the-cp-switch.

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to do this is to write a shell script that calls the Groovy/Java program and passes the desired classpath on the command line.