# running groovy script from any user directory on linux

Tags: linux, groovy

I've put together a utility script in groovy and would like to run it in any directory as needed without having to specify full path to it. As in `$> groovy myScript.groovy`

I've added the path to it's parent directory to PATH in .profile, sourced it, but keep gettig 'command not found' error. Any idea where to look for the problem, conceptually speaking?

**Where things are:**

First line of my PostBuilder.groovy script: #!/usr/bin/env groovy`

PATH in .profile: `export PATH=$PATH:/home/me/work/web/MyProject/public_html`

The error I'm getting now trying to execute the script in my home directory:

```
Caught: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/me/PostBuilder.groovy (/home/me/PostBuilder.groovy)
```

FYI, my Groovy/Grails set up works just fine so I'm thinking installation of groovy itself is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more likely what you really want is to:

1. Add the path the script is in to your PATH environment variable, and
2. Make it executable via `chmod u+x`, and
3. Shebang it with `#!/usr/bin/env groovy` (or your equivalent).

Comment: ... just tried playing with this, still no joy, added more details to question.

Comment: @vector I don't understand your shebang.

Comment: my groovy installation sits in /home/me/groovy instead of /usr/bin/env

Comment: @vector Then it's still wrong, IMO. Search for "unix shebang" to see what it actually does.

Comment: @vector You can't supply `groovy` directly as the target of the shebang, as it turns out.  Has to be a binary, and `groovy` is a shell script (see comments in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479731/shebang-and-groovy).  So, letting `env` execute groovy is the workaround for that.

Comment: @vector To clarify Dave's idea:  you supply that stuff as listed, then you can run `PostBuilder.groovy` on the command line - no preceding `groovy` required, which is what I think you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Add the path to `groovy/bin` to your `PATH`.  Then you can run groovy, but you'd still need to be in the directory of your .groovy script, or supply full path, to execute.