# Running Groovy script from the command line

Tags: unix, groovy

When I did `which groovy`, I got the below output:

```
/usr/local/bin/groovy
```

So I went ahead and created a `helloworld.groovy` with the below content

```
#!/usr/local/bin/groovy
println "hello world"
```

After that I did `chmod +x helloworld.groovy` and attempted to run the file with `./hellworld.groovy` and sadly, I got this error `./helloworld.groovy: line 2: print: command not found`

I could get rid of the error by changing to

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
println "hello world"
```

Why would the first method cause the error?

Comment: There's a great discussion on this topic in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306139/how-do-i-include-jars-in-a-groovy-script/8945888#8945888

Comment: And also on the same question... http://stackoverflow.com/a/9692013/673282

Answer (score 84):

You need to run the script like this:

```
groovy helloworld.groovy
```

Comment: or just `groovy helloworld`. :)

Comment: since groovy is also a scripting language, we should be able to run it like perl or python right? so the question is why `./helloworld.groovy` returns an error about the `println`. what is the difference between `#!/usr/local/bin/groovy` and `#!/usr/bin/env groovy`?

Comment: `#!/usr/local/bin/groovy` is the exact location where groovy is installed. That makes the script not portable to another system where groovy is installed elsewhere. This however `#!/usr/bin/env` groovy calls the the program "/usr/bin/env" with the argument "groovy", and /usr/bin/env is searching your PATH variable to call "groovy". <br> BTW: the better shebang is `#! /usr/bin/env`. Note the space between ! and /. That way the first 4 bytes of every "Script" are identical (that is old school to make this the "magic number" of the file)

Comment: @angel-osphere Why is it better to have the first 4 characters identical? Is there any real benefit? (e.g., does it work better under different shells/ un*x environments, etc?)

Comment: @DrUseful maybe if you're running on a PDP-11, lol. Otherwise, I don't think it matters. (Magic numbers are 8-bytes anyway, and modern (past 10 years at least) UNIX exec() functions only look for the 2 bytes #! to determine if it's a script or not)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
sed '1,2d' "$0"|$(which groovy) /dev/stdin; exit;

println("hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
#!groovy
println("hello world!")
```

```sh
$ chmod +x script.groovy
$ ./script.groovy
```

Comment: Please provide a description to your code and how it answers the question.

Comment: This is not an answer

Answer (score -1):

It will work on Linux kernel 2.6.28 (confirmed on 4.9.x). It won't work on FreeBSD and other Unix flavors.

Your `/usr/local/bin/groovy` is a shell script wrapping the Java runtime running Groovy.

See the *Interpreter Scripts* section of *[EXECVE(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)* and *[EXECVE(2)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=execve&sektion=2)*.

Comment: Version 4.9.x of what?