# Can I avoid using Grape to load modules in Groovy?

Tags: java, maven, groovy, groovy-grape

I am writing my first automation script in groovy and I've hit a roadblock.
While making use of the AntBuilder class to run sshexec() I run into the following error:

```
: Problem: failed to create task or type sshexec
Cause: the class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.SSHExec was not found.
    This looks like one of Ant's optional components.
Action: Check that the appropriate optional JAR exists in
    -ANT_HOME\lib
    -the IDE Ant configuration dialogs

Do not panic, this is a common problem.
The commonest cause is a missing JAR.

This is not a bug; it is a configuration problem
```

So far the best solution I've found for this is to use

```
Grape.grab(group : "com.jcraft", module : "jsch", classLoader : this.class.classLoader.rootLoader)
Grape.grab(group:"ant", module:"ant-jsch", classLoader:this.class.classLoader.rootLoader)
```

in order to load the required modules.
However, I would like to eliminate the lag time of Grape downloading the jars from the remote Maven repository.

Is there a way to download and save modules for future use, perhaps in the JAVA_PATH or something to that effect?

Comment: The artefacts should be cached in user.home_dir/.m2/repository... does this program not run faster the second time around?

Comment: Unfortunately it runs just as slowly on subsequent runs. Does not appear to be caching, nor do I have a .m2 directory under my user. Is the path different on Win machines?

Comment: The repo is still under your home directory on windows. All you need is the right jars on your classpath, it doesn't matter how they get there.

Comment: Appreciate it Dave, is there any configuration needed after adding the jars to the class path? Furthermore, is there a separate Groovy class path from a Java one? The documentation I've found so far has been lacking

Comment: There's only one classpath; the JVM one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the required jars to %ANT_HOME% and %GROOVY_HOME% wasn't working.

The solution is to put the jars under %USERPROFILE%.groovy\lib - after which the Grape calls are no longer necessary. Hopefully this is useful to others with the same issue.

Thanks to [Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438992/dave-newton) for getting me on the right track.

- [Source: groovy.codehaus.org](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Running) see the "Adding things to the classpath" heading
- [Source: related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/254448/1387419)

Comment: I'd be a little cautious about putting them in an environment-wide location, since you may need different libraries, or different versions of the same libraries, when running other scripts. If you *really* have a restriction of only using the Groovy file (which is a *weird* restriction, btw!) you may not have an option, but it can cause problems down the line.

Comment: Well the idea is to cleanup the current build configuration by replacing .bat and ant .xml files with an all-encompassing groovy script, however replacing the ant sshexec calls simply wasn't working out of the box in groovy. If there is a cleaner way of installing the libraries locally as opposed to downloading each time I'm all ears :) Trying to avoid Grape usage as it just seems to be complicating what I think should be a simple configuration issue.

Comment: It shouldn't be downloading them each time, though. Putting the jars on the classpath (assuming no grape, I mean) should be sufficient.

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding the classpath then, when I `echo %CLASSPATH%` in terminal it refers to a specific jar file. Am I supposed to put the jars I downloaded in the same folder as this one?

Comment: No, the classpath contains a list of all the jar files, and class directories, available to a Java app.

Comment: So if my classpath says a specific jar then that is the only file available to my Java apps?

Comment: Correct (although it may depend on the Java version; I vaguely remember earlier versions would automatically add the current directory, but I could be completely wrong on that). Not sure if the `-cp` command-line arg replaces `$CLASSPATH` or not; you'd have to check.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Grape annotations to download the scripts dependencies at runtime:

```
@Grapes([
    @Grab(group='org.apache.ant', module='ant-jsch', version='1.8.3'),
    @GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)
])

def ant = new AntBuilder()

ant.sshexec(host:"somehost", username:"yo", password:"dude", command:"ls")
```

If you're behind a firewall, you could also configure the location of your Maven repository:

```
@GrabResolver(name="my-repo", root="http://my.hostname/maven/repo")
```

Final tip, the property **groovy.grape.autoDownload** can be used to control whether grape does a remote download or just uses its cached files.

```
groovy -Dgroovy.grape.autoDownload=false myscript.groovy
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your only going to be running your code on a couple of machines I would create a grapeConfig.xml file and set the ivy.cache.ttl.default to something like 30 days. This will tell Grape that if you have a dependency which uses a version range to only check remote repositories for updated dependencies every 30 days. See [this post](http://spring-java-ee.posterous.com/fixing-slow-grab-dependencies-issue-with-groo) for more details.

Comment: One of the limitations of the system I'm working with is that the groovy script is the only file allowed. Trying to resolve clutter.