# How do I import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.Repository

Tags: nexus, nexus3

We are running Nexus:3.29.2 and I want to add a groovy script to a Admin-Execute task. To start I am attempting to execute the following sample script:

```
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.Repository

repository.repositoryManager.browse().each { Repository currentRepository ->
  // do some stuff in each repository
  log.info("Found repository: " + currentRepository)
}
```

But the task fails and the log shows: *unable to resolve class org.sonatype.nexus.repository.Repository*

Where is the groovy script supposed to import from?

Comment: I have been running [the following script](https://github.com/ansible-ThoTeam/nexus3-oss/blob/master/files/groovy/delete_repo.groovy) almost daily in automated builds for approx. the last 2 years without any sort of problem. Although not exactly your above script, I'm 99.99999% sure I can say I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: The exercise that I described works as expected in our lab environment. But not in our development environment which runs inside a different network. It appears essentially that none of the import statements succeed.

So expanding on my original question asking where the groovy script imports from . . . Is there a repository internal to Nexus from which scripts import from? Or do the scripts import from an external Maven repository? Or does our Nexus instance import from some external Nexus repository?

Comment: The groovy script must run inside a running nexus environment. From your question it is not absolutely clear if this is the case...

Comment: It is a running environment. We have several maven and docker repositories that we make use of every day. One other possibly notable piece of information . . . This Nexus instance does not have access to the public internet.

Answer (score 3):

When the Groovy script runs inside Nexus (it is implied from your question), it has access to all Nexus JARs, so no explicit import should be required.

The `org.sonatype.nexus.repository.Repository` interface is located in `nexus-repository-config-<VERSION>.jar`. E.g. for Nexus OSS 3.36.0 the exact location would be `$NEXUS_HOME/system/org/sonatype/nexus/nexus-repository-config/3.36.0-01/nexus-repository-config-3.36.0-01.jar`.

When the Groovy script runs outside Nexus, just put all necessary JARs into `~/.groovy/lib`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254385/how-do-i-auto-load-a-database-jar-in-groovy-without-using-the-cp-switch)